# How to initialize a string with a repeating character with specific length in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the equivalent of this Java code in Dart?

```
int precision = 2; // depends on locale
String f = "0".repeat(precision); // 00
String format = "0." + f; // "0.00"
```

I don't like to construct via loop as it produces a lot of garbage.

Comment: [num.toStringAsFixed()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html)

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately, `toStringAsFixed` is not localized. I need to use a `NumberFormat` to get the right decimal separator.

Comment: so use `'0' * precision` - I mean: `'0.${'0' * precision}'`

Comment: @MartinBraun Are you building a format string for `NumberFormat`?  If so, even though `toStringAsFixed` is not localized, you could use it as input to `NumberFormat`, which *expects* `.` as a format specifier: `NumberFormat(0.0.toStringAsFixed(precision)).format(someNumber)`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Great! Please make an official answer which I can accept, because I wish this question to be answered. I'd love to have yours and pskink's way in one answer to wrap things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question: [as pskink noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095634/#comment134201262_76095634), the simplest way to create a repeating `String` is to use [`String.operator *`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/operator_multiply.html):

```dart
print('-' * 10); // Prints: ----------
```

Since your specific use case appears to be generating a format string to use with [`NumberFormat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html), [as pskink also noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095634/#comment134200984_76095634), you alternatively could use [`num.toStringAsFixed()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095634/#comment134200984_76095634).  It doesn't matter that `toStringAsFixed` doesn't output a localized decimal separator since `NumberFormat` expects `.` as a format specifier:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var someNumber = 628.3185;
  var precision = 2;
  var format = 0.toStringAsFixed(precision); // 0.00
  print(NumberFormat(format).format(someNumber)); // Prints: 628.32
}
```